# Vanishing derivative of determinant at degenerate points

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a smooth, square matrix valued function
\begin{equation}
A\in C^\infty(\mathbb R,Mat_{n\times n}\mathbb C)
\end{equation}
such that at the point $0\in\mathbb R$ the matrix $A(0)$ maps at least two independent vectors to the zero vector, that is the kernel of $A(0)$ is at least two-dimensional.

My claim is that the derivative of the determinant of $A$ has to vanish at $0$, that is
\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det A(t)=0
\end{equation}

How would one go about proving something of this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(0)=USV^\ast$ be a singular value decomposition with the singular values on the diagonal of $S$ arranged in *ascending* order. As the nullity of $A(0)$ is at least two, the first columns of $S(0)$ are zero.

Define $S(t)=U^\ast A(t)V$ for every $t$ and denote by $\mathbf s_j(t)$ denotes the $j$-th column of $S(t)$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det S(t)
&=\det(\dot{\mathbf s}_1(0),\mathbf s_2(0),\mathbf s_3(0),\mathbf s_4(0)\ldots,\mathbf s_n(0))\\
&\phantom{=} + \det(\mathbf s_1(0),\dot{\mathbf s}_2(0),\mathbf s_3(0),\mathbf s_4(0),\ldots,\mathbf s_n(0))\\
&\phantom{=} + \det(\mathbf s_1(0),\mathbf s_2(0),\dot{\mathbf s}_3(0),\mathbf s_4(0),\ldots,\mathbf s_n(0)) + \cdots,
\end{align*}
$$
which is equal to zero because $\mathbf s_1(0)=\mathbf s_2(0)=0$. Consequently, $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det A(t)=\det(UV^\ast)\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det S(t)=0$.